# How to check if a method is called before another one got called

Tags: javascript, sinon, ava

I have a method called `mainMethod()` and it returns a promise. 
This method contains several methods `m1()`, `m2()`...,`m5()`.
Now I am making a unit test using `sinon`,

I want to check if `m1()` is called and `m2()` is **not** called.

Because I have an array that **not empty** after `m1()` is called but it **will be empty** after `m2()` is called.

I want to make a check or test after `m1()` is called and before `m2()` is called.

Is it  possible using `sinon`?

Comment: chain the promises.

Comment: Please provide code samples of what `mainMethod` looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using Sinon is possible. It has `calledAfter` and `calledBefore`.

http://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.1.3/spies/

For example

```
it('some testing', function() {
    var m1 = { method: function () {} };
    var m2 = { method: function () {} };

    var spyM1 = sinon.spy(m1, "method");
    var spyM2 = sinon.spy(m2, "method");

    m1.method(42);
    m2.method(1);

    assert(spyM1.calledBefore(spyM2));
    assert(spyM2.calledAfter(spyM1));
});
```